# Share design data between jinja2 and js

Tags: flask

I'm developing an app in flask. I have to tables, one renders on the server side using jinja2 and the other one is a live table that renders dynamically using socketio. They are in different routes but the tables look the same in design.

My problem relies on the rendering, I iterate through the same database in both cases but in the dynamic part i get the json and render it with mustache and the static table do the same but with jinja2. I need to store data related with states and categories that i obtain from the database for every row and use it for rendering in both routes.

basically I want to know where to store this relationship:

```
{category_id:{icon:x, color:y, name:z}}
```

I'm almost sure that whatever solution I get I would eventually need this as a jquery object (my current solution but a single change in that data means change multiple places on different templates) so i can then access on rendering to get the dynamic data, but... that doesn't mean i now how to get there nor how to share the same data structure between flask jinja and js. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use Flask sessions to store data between views.

```
from flask import session
```

Then you can set it:

```
session['config'] = {category_id:{icon:x, color:y, name:z}}
```

And get it, and pass it to your view:

```
 default_config = {category_id:{icon:x, color:y, name:z}}
 config = session.get('config', default_config)
```